# Why does Syncfusion Xamarin.Forms DataForm ignore grid attached properties for column span?

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion.xforms

I have the following code in a xamarin forms page:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:df="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.DataForm;assembly=Syncfusion.SfDataForm.XForms"
             x:Class="RsInvPro.Views.InventoryEditView">

  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <Binding Path="InventoryEditViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           
           
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveChangesCommand}"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelChangesCommand}"></Button>
            <StackLayout
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                x:Name="stackLayout"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <df:SfDataForm
                    x:Name="dataForm"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    DataObject="{Binding InventoryRow}" />
            </StackLayout>
 

        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the simulator output:
[image]

Comment: please do not post code as images

Comment: posting code as images is against the SO site rules.  It is not a question of my personal preferences

Comment: I changed it.... and the answer is?

Comment: You have three columns and ColumnSpan=2, it appears to be doing exactly what you are telling it to do.

Comment: Columns also start at index 0, you're settings the Save and Cancel buttons on column 1 and 2 instead 0 and 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 3 column grid.

this tells your layout to start in Col 0 and span 2 columns, which is exactly what it is doing.

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
```

If you want it to span the entire Grid, use `ColumnSpan="3"`

Comment: That's what I get for staring at this for hours and making changes.  Sometimes a view without the forest is golden.  Thanks...